# Using range in curve_fit allows "x" value of list(range(x,y)) to be any number, but not "y" value

Tags: python, range, curve-fitting

I'm using curve_fit to fit a polynomial to my data, which has 200 indices.

Here is my code:

```
def func3(x, a, b, c, d):    
    return (a)*((x)**3) + (b)*((x)**2) + c*x + d
weight1 = np.ones(len(xdata))
weight1[[list(range(3900,89))]] = 0.01 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func3, data, ydata, p0=(1, 1, 1, 10), 
sigma=weight1) 
poly = func3(xdata1, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]) 
pl.plot(xdata, poly)
```

Now, if the second value of range (89) goes past 200 (lets say 300), I get an error: `IndexError: index 300 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 199`.

But when the first value of range is a value higher than 200 (like 3900 in this case), I don't get an error. Rather my fit changes.

So, what does the first value of range actually stand for here? I thought it was the index value of my data point, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `range(start_value, end_value)` gives `end_value - start_value` elements, but if `start_value` is bigger then `end_value` then you get empty list - and you don't have problem with too big index. See `print( list(range(3900,89)) )`

Comment: see `print( list(range(0,9)) )`, `print( list(range(9,0)) )` and `print( list(range(9,0,-1)) )`